# How to get the Unicode Code Point (as in from the database) in Python 3

Tags: python, unicode

For the [copyright sign](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f63e), 
the unicode website lists "U+00A9"

Is there a way for me to get that exact number,  or string, from Python 3 of any Unicode point?

I have tried all of the following:

```
ord('©') = 169
'©'.encode('unicode_escape') = b'\\xa9'
'\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN}'.encode('utf-8') = b'\xc2\xa9'
```

and I do not know what else to try. I'm looking for a solution that would work for all Unicode Code Points (including, for instance the ) whose code is 5 digits and starts with a 1 (I.e. `1F44D`)

Comment: For the record, `ord('©')` is producing that number. It's just displayed in unpadded decimal, `169`, where `00A9` is zero padded hexadecimal. The values are the same. If you did `hex(ord('©'))` you'd get `'0xa9'` or to get the padding, no leading `0x` and matching capitalization, use formatting operations: `'{:04X}'.format(ord('©'))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> 'U+{:04X}'.format(ord('©'))
'U+00A9'
```

Comment: I like this answer however I updated my question. I am looking for a way to do this for characters that start with `1` as well.